# Why is this AngularJS ng-repeat example not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Sorry for asking this.
But I searched everywhere and I can't understand why this example is not working:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="VenuesController">
            <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
                <!-- Table -->
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p align=center>{{field.name}} - {{field.sport}} {{field.price}}
                        </p></td>
                        <td><p align=center></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="hour in field.hours">
                        <td><p align=center>{{hour.from}} - {{hour.to}}</p></td>
                        <td><p align=center><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">{{hour.state}}</button></p></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.searchFieldsState = function() {

    $scope.fields = [
        {'name': 'Cancha 1', 'sport': 'Futbol', 'price': '$150',
            'hours' : [
                {'from': '10:00', 'to': '11:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '11:00', 'to': '12:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '12:00', 'to': '13:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '13:00', 'to': '14:00', 'state': 'Libre'}
                ]
        },
        {'name': 'Cancha 2', 'sport': 'Futbol', 'price': '$170',
            'hours' : [
                {'from': '10:00', 'to': '11:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '11:00', 'to': '12:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '12:00', 'to': '13:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '13:00', 'to': '14:00', 'state': 'Libre'}
            ]
        },
        {'name': 'Cancha 3', 'sport': 'Tenis', 'price': '$170',
            'hours' : [
                {'from': '10:00', 'to': '11:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '11:00', 'to': '12:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '12:00', 'to': '13:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '13:00', 'to': '14:00', 'state': 'Libre'}
            ]
        }
    ];
};
```

I'm sure that the function `searchFieldsState` is being executed because I used a `console.log` command for debugging purposes.

So, can anyone see any mistake here? A fresh eye would be helpful.

Thank you very much in advance.

UPDATE:

I initialized the $scope.fields outside the function and ng-repeat worked. But this is not what I need so... The problem persist

I will add my navbar code because I think it is related with this issue:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#/sportmap">SportMap</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/lockerroom">Ingresar</a></li>
        <li ><a ng-controller="VenuesController" href="#/venue">Administraci&oacute;n</a></li>
      </ul>
```

The route:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/index', {
        templateUrl: 'search.html',
        controller: 'VenuesController',
        restricted: false
    }).
    when('/venue', {
        templateUrl: 'venue.html',
        controller: 'VenuesController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index'
    });
```

}]);

Thank you guys!

---

Updating with the working code:

The HTML file with the ng-repeat was ok.

I had to modify the navbar.html template

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#/sportmap">SportMap</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/lockerroom">Ingresar</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#/venue/1" >Administraci&oacute;n</a></li>
</ul>
```

So then I changed the route

```
when('/venue/:venueid', {
   templateUrl: 'venue.html',
   controller: 'VenuesController'
}).
```

with this I receive a parameter called venueid. And then...

the magical trick based in Carlos Barcelona suggestion:

```
var venuesControllers = angular.module('myApp');

venuesControllers.controller('VenuesController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$location', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, $resource, $location, $routeParams) {

//This is a venue initialization it may be no needed. TODO: try not to use it.
$scope.venue = {city: "", sport: "", venueid: ""};

//Here I just declare the function

$scope.showVenueFields = function () {
    // To search by city and/or sport
    console.log($scope.venue.venueid);
    $scope.venue.name = 'El Andén';
    $scope.venue.fields = [
        {'name': 'Cancha 1', 'sport': 'Futbol', 'price': '$150',
            'hours' : [
                {'from': '10:00', 'to': '11:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '11:00', 'to': '12:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '12:00', 'to': '13:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '13:00', 'to': '14:00', 'state': 'Libre'}
            ]
        },
        {'name': 'Cancha 2', 'sport': 'Futbol', 'price': '$170',
            'hours' : [
                {'from': '10:00', 'to': '11:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '11:00', 'to': '12:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '12:00', 'to': '13:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '13:00', 'to': '14:00', 'state': 'Libre'}
            ]
        },
        {'name': 'Cancha 3', 'sport': 'Tenis', 'price': '$170',
            'hours' : [
                {'from': '10:00', 'to': '11:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '11:00', 'to': '12:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '12:00', 'to': '13:00', 'state': 'Libre'},
                {'from': '13:00', 'to': '14:00', 'state': 'Libre'}
            ]
        }
    ];
}


if ($routeParams.venueid){
    console.log("Leo los parametros");
    $scope.venue.venueid = $routeParams.venueid;
    //Here I really call the function and initialize the venue.fields
    $scope.showVenueFields();

} else {
    // Do something
}



// this ends the controller's declaration
}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried defining $scope.fields outside of the searchFieldsState function? It is possible that Angular is creating a local $scope object inside of the function, and your ng-repeat directive is looking for a 'fields' property within the VenuesController's main scope (I might be totally wrong).

Comment: do not forget to accept the answer if it was good for you. :)

Comment: @MichaelZalla I tried and when I do that it works. So you may be right.

Comment: @CarlosBarcelona I will.But I still need help with this :-)

Comment: @GaboLato the update is a different topic, this one relates to the ngRouter, what is the issue? I see the links won't work, but is this the problem? I would recommend you to open a new question

Comment: @CarlosBarcelona It was all part of the same issue. I will explain myself with a comment under your answer and I will accept it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the way the Controller is called

instead of this:

```
$scope.searchFieldsState = function() {
  $scope.fields = [
    {'name': 'Cancha 1', 'sport': 'Futbol', 'price': '$150',
        'hours' : [
 etc...
```

type this:

```
function VenuesController($scope) {
  $scope.fields = [
    {'name': 'Cancha 1', 'sport': 'Futbol', 'price': '$150',
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work but it was a good observation. I will update my question I belive the way I arrive that route it's the cause of the problem

Comment: Ok. The problem was that I was on index.html template at the beginng using VenuesController so the controller has been initialized.

Comment: So after that my link redirects me tothe venue.html template wich has the same controller and that initialize the controller again but the way a I wrote the searchFieldsState function it has to be called from an ng-click it won't run when the page is loading, and in order to get the ng-repeat working i needed those values loaded on the scope so I made sure the function runs at the end of my controller's initialization. I will update with my code working tonight

Comment: @GaboLato happy to help you! I see you are in the learning process, check this web site http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GtaQ0oMGIl/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs it really helped me :)